# Limit concurrent http requests with RxJS and Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've seen this question asked before but the responses have always been unsatisfying for me, so i'll try and be precise:

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs and want to queue up a lot of http requests and i want to chain those into other operations like this:

```
urls$.flatMap(x => fetchUrls(x)).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

url$ being a Observable and fetchUrls being a method returning a new Observable. This would work well, except the first stream comming from urls$ is pretty fast and the fetchUrls method is slow (doing http request/response). I end up with 200+ http requests running at once.

I think leaving 200+ pending http requests on the client would be asking for trouble so i want to somehow pool the requests and i read that it is possible to set the maximum concurrent requests when using [mergeMap](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap)/flatMap, which is really nice.

I created a playground for the thing here: 
http://www.webpackbin.com/EkQXtBEwz
I have a method called fakeHttpLookup which delays the response by a second and feeding it with a list of 200 urls - if run sequentially would take 200 seconds. With the maxConcurrent set to 5 i guess, best case it would take care of the whole stream in 40 seconds.

The thing is - I can't get it to work. It does take the first 5 but then halts. It never completes the whole stream.

I would expect to see the counter increment with 5 for each second passed, illustrating 5 concurrent http requests at a time.

Can anyone help? I can live with only running one request at a time - i could buffer of 5 of those at a time, but the important thing here is not to queue up all 200 at once - or only taking the first few.

TLDR:
I want to be able to queue/pool http requests and the stream must be able to limit the number of requests without guessing at a hard coded wait delay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.flatMap()`, aka [`.mergeMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) has an optional argument 'concurrency'

> mergeMap(project: function(value: T, ?index: number): Observable, resultSelector: function(outerValue: T, innerValue: I, outerIndex: number, innerIndex: number): any, *concurrent: number*)

So its simply a matter of:

```js
function fetch(id) {
  return Rx.Observable.of(id)
    .do(i => console.log(`fetching request ${i}`))
    .delay(2 * 1000);
}

Rx.Observable.range(1, 20)
  .flatMap(id => fetch(id), null, 5)
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.0.3/Rx.js"></script>
```

to execute 5 concurrent requests

Comment: i looked at your fiddle but it seems that you put your concurrency `5` as arg for the `resultSelector` func ?

Comment: I played around with it a bit - you can try and edit if you think you can hack it to work? I tried as second and as third argument - neither worked for me

Comment: i have updated my answer with a working example, check it out

Comment: For some reason, your fetch returns something that does chain, and my new Subject() does not. Even though it doesn't work for me, i can see that your example does work... Guess i'll have to make a new question once i figure out what the underlying problem is ;)

Comment: Just checked your playground, your `fakeHttpLookup` returns a Observable which never completes because you only invoke `next` on it. This results in the initial concurrent requests never finishing and the `mergeMap` never starting the next requests

Comment: I just came back here to write excatly that, but seeing you beat me to it - thanks :)