# rxjs call 2 services per item in a array in a interval

Tags: arrays, angular, rxjs

I have and array of 'N' ids, i would like to consume per each item 2 services  and wrap all in a forkjoin with a timer, because i would not like to send 1000 request at the same time, i expect each item was procces in 10 seconds,the ideas is know what ids was procesed and which wasn't, at the subcribe.

```
var arraytoprocess=[...this.selection.selected]; //array of ids
var arraytoprocessObs$=[];
for (let index = 0; index < arraytoprocess.length; index++)
{
  const obs1$=this._api.service1(+arraytoprocess[index].id);
  const obs2$=this._api.service2(+arraytoprocess[index].id);
  const obs$=forkJoin([obs1$,obs2$])
  arraytoprocessObs$.push(obs$)
}
//call each item of the arraytoprocessObs$ per 10 seconds 
magiccodewithpipes().subcribe()
```

Comment: Why not some kind of pool like of 5 calls in parallel max at any time? It feels more optimized than choosing an arbitrary 10 seconds wait between 2 calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit concurrent http requests with RxJS and Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895853/limit-concurrent-http-requests-with-rxjs-and-angular2)

Comment: I don´t send the 5  calls in parallel because I kwow the api maybe in some case can be blocked by the huge consume, becuse the selection of ids for process in some cases ca reach 10 000 ids *2, while other fix the concurrency performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I figure out with the help of this [Limit concurrent http requests with RxJS and Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41895853/limit-concurrent-http-requests-with-rxjs-and-angular2) this aproach, and its works like a charm each item is processed per 5 seconds and I can manage the two observes like one.

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { concat, forkJoin, from, Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, delay, flatMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  todos: Array<Todo>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('ngOnInit');

    var arraytoprocess = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10];
    var arraytoprocessObs$ = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < arraytoprocess.length; index++) {
      const obs1$ = this.http.get(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + arraytoprocess[index]
      );
      const obs2$ = this.http.get(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + arraytoprocess[index]
      );
      const obs$ = forkJoin([obs1$, obs2$]);
      arraytoprocessObs$.push(obs$);
    }

    concat(...arraytoprocessObs$)
      .pipe(
        tap(x => console.log(x)),
        //flatMap(x => fetch(x), null, 5)
        concatMap(item => of(item).pipe(delay(5000)))
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('asd' + JSON.stringify(response));
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
  }
}
export interface Todo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}
```

[stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-simple-http-get-auj18k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)